# What is the difference between open access and open archive?

Tags: journals, open-access, terminology, elsevier

In Elsevier [ScienceDirect](http://www.sciencedirect.com) search, there are two types of access type filters; Open Access articles and Open Archive articles. What is the difference between these two? Is there a notable difference between the terms themselves?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Elsevier uses these terms, "open access" means an article is free to access as soon as it is published. "Open archive" means an article is published in a journal that makes articles available for free after some embargo period (not immediately when it is published).

More on [Open Archive](http://www.elsevier.com/about/open-science/open-access/open-archive):

> Elsevier enables subscribers and the general public to have free access to archived material in 98 Elsevier journals... Articles featured in the archives are free for everyone to read and download and are made available after an embargo period.

Comment: What's with the embargo period for open archive? Why the delay? How are those articles different from open access articles by nature?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac The difference is that the authors of those articles did not choose to publish them in an open access journal, or as open access articles in a hybrid OA journal. That's all.

Comment: Does this mean open archive facility is an added advantage to general authors who didn't pay for the open access in Elsevier? If that is so, what should an author satisfy to attain this added privilege?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Yes, and publish in a journal that's an Open Archive journal. (Follow the link to learn more)

Comment: It appears that many  (or maybe all) of the 98 journals on that list simply "open archive" *all* of their articles after the embargo period. The author doesn't have to do or pay anything.

Comment: So I see. There is a completely separate list of journal titles in Elsevier that becomes OA-like access after a certain period called the embargo period. This is totally different from other Elsevier titles like *Pattern Recognition Letters*, right? May I know what is the rationale behind grouping journals in these two groups? (PS: Thanks for the link @ff524)

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac: as far as I know, the open archive was installed by Elsevier in response to the "Cost of knowledge" pledge of about 15k scientists not to get involved with Elsevier anymore.

Comment: That's amazing, why hasn't anyone done the same for IEEE?